# Retrieving single record from xml using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am new to jquery and I have an xml document which I would like ajax to only display that one record(container) instead of it displaying all the other records(containers). Currently its displaying all records , instead I would like it to display one for example question in code 2.

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
<record>
<code>1</code>
<question>what is your name</question>
</record>
<record>
<code>2</code>
<question>what is your day</question>
</record>
</container>
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:'my.xml',
    dataType:'xml',
    success: function(data){


        function question(e)
        {

                $(data).find('container record').each(function()
                {
                var code = $(this).find('code').text();
                if (code == 2)
                {
                    var record = $(this).find('question').text();
                    $('.timeline').append($('<P />',{text:record}));
                }
                else
                {

                    $('.timeline').append($('<P />',''));
                }


                });

        }
        question();
    },
    error: function(){
        $('.timeline').text('Failed to read feed');
    }   
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="timeline">

</div>
```

Comment: If you only want one you need to define criteria used to filter that one out

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [**`:eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector :

```js
$.ajax({
    url:'my.xml',
    dataType:'xml',
    success: function(data){
        function question(no) {
            var $record = $(data).find('record:eq('+no+')');
            if ($record.find('code').text() == '2') {
                $('.timeline').append($('<P />', {text: $record.find('question').text() }))
            } else {
                $('.timeline').append($('<P />',''));
            }
        }
        question(0); //1, 2, 3 and so on
    },
    error: function(){
        $('.timeline').text('Failed to read feed');
    }   
});
```